# Using a chrome extension to make a text div into a web link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I use a website for listing management for walmart marketplace sales.  Theres a column with a product ID in it (div.slick-cell.l4.r4).  This ID is plain text.  Im trying to turn it into a link "https://www.walmart.com/ip/productIDhere" so I can just click on them to see product page.

So I made a simple chrome extension to attempt this.  I can figure out how to make the product ID cell link to https://www.walmart.com/ip/ but I cannot figure out how to also append the ID so its a real link.

js code:

```
$('div.slick-cell.l4.r4').each(function() {
var link = $(this).html();
$(this).contents().wrap('<a href="http://www.walmart.com/ip/"></a>');
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you started with and what you want to result to be?

Comment: did you add the jQuery lib to your extension? If not, you need to change the code to plain js like document.querySelectorAll('div.slick-cell.l4.r4').forEach(e => .....);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at this a bit more since commenting, I believe what you will want is:

```
$('div.slick-cell.l4.r4').wrapInner(function() { 
    return "<a href='http://www.walmart.com/ip/" + $(this).text() + "'></a>";
});
```

This will put an `<a>` inside the `<div>` (could probably wrap it outer too with .wrap, but inner seems better to me) using the div's text contents as part of the href and your string as the rest.